# Best way to get data from Ms Access Mdb file to sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2005, vba

We use a software which uses Sql server 2005 as back-end.

The problem is we have data coming in access file and we need to store it in sql server tables.

I have the sql server tables ready.

I don't need all the data i get in MDB access file but need specific columns from access and then store it in SQL server.

I get fresh access tables every week and need to migrate it to tables in SQL Server.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set up an [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) package to do this

- [An Introduction to SSIS - Tutorial](http://www.accelebrate.com/sql_training/ssis_tutorial.htm)
- [Deploying and running SSIS packages](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/09/16/deploying-ssis-packages-in-sql-server-2005/)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use Access as a client interface, you could open 2 connections:

- An ADODB or ODBC connection to the Access database
- An ADODB or ODBC connection to the SQL server

You'll open a recordset on each connection, then browse the Access Database Recordset to fill the SQL server recordset with code such as:

```
Do while not rsACCESS.eof
    rsSQL.addNew
    For each rsField in rsACCESS.field
        rsSQL.fields(rsField.name) = rsField
    Next rsField
    rsSQL.update
    rsACCESS.moveNext
Loop
```

Of course you'll have to make sure that your rsSQl recordset is updatable and so on ...

Answer (score 0):

SSMA will do this a well. You can setup a job and save it to easily run it again.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/migration.aspx